# paypal-checkout-serversdk with Django

Tags: python, django, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I want to integrate Paypal into my Django App. I tried using `django-paypal` it worked fine but it stopped working suddenly, PayPal was not sending confirmation to the notify URL anymore but it again started working now, so I decided that I will do this with python SDK but their not many docs online on how to achieve it I tried `paypal-checkout-serversdk` which is the newer version and could;t get it to work then I tried `paypalrestsdk` and no luck there as well there are docs on how to implement it on client-side and how to do it on the server side but I could not figure out how out.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is super low on details on where you've gone wrong.

Use the newest Python-Checkout-SDK for the v2/checkout/orders API.

At a very high level, create two routes, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order', [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls). These routes should return JSON data, and only JSON data (no HTML, text, or anything else when called).

Pair your two routes with the following approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Ten fit that into your django app front-end however you best want.

The back end 'Capture Order' route should record a any successful transaction in your database and mark the cart/order as paid before returning its JSON data to the client.

Comment: can you tell me what to send back in my capture route...

Comment: The above approval flow is set to handle a full v2/checkout/orders response, so you could propagate the entire thing back. Or be more selective, it's up to you.  It's important for error details to be there in the expected format so that recoverable errors can be handled.